# How to Check If A Plugin Is Enabled Through API?

Tags: plugins, multisite

How to find out if a particular plugin is enabled in a sub-blog in a multisite blog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm, I am not entirely sure about mechanics here. Usual [`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) checks if plugin is in `active_plugins` option.

By this logic you could probably retrieve `active_plugins` of specific blog with [`get_blog_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_option) and check it for plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Ya what Rarst said, for his example you can do something like the following but it returns an array with active plugin name/plugin_filename.php

> get_option('active_plugins');

You can try using use the global $plugin to get a lot more data.

```
global $plugins;

$plugins = array(
            'all' => apply_filters( 'all_plugins', get_plugins() ),
            'search' => array(),
            'active' => array(),
            'inactive' => array(),
            'recently_activated' => array(),
            'upgrade' => array(),
            'mustuse' => array(),
            'dropins' => array()
        );
```