# How to tell if Jetpack's Photon is active?

Tags: plugins, plugin-jetpack

There are multiple ways to identify if a plugin is active ([here's one)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14410/how-to-check-if-a-plugin-is-enabled-through-api) but how can we identify if a specific JetPack component is active, for example [Photon](http://jetpack.me/support/photon/)?

Comment: Maybe, but it depends on how the particular component operates. If the component leaves fingerprints in the source code you should be able to identify it. But that begs at least one question: How/where do you need to identify if the plugin is active? Do you need to scan the site's front end or do you have code running on the site-- probably a plugin of some kind?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We just committed a new function to Jetpack Trunk, and it should be enabled in the next release, `Jetpack::is_module_active()` --

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/716884

Then you can just call:

```
if( class_exists( 'Jetpack' ) && Jetpack::is_module_active( 'contact-form' ) ) {}
```

Or at least, you will once the next version releases, and the user has their Jetpack updated.  :)  If you'd like to preserve the backward compatability, you can just do:

```
if( class_exists( 'Jetpack' ) && in_array( 'contact-form', Jetpack::get_active_modules() ) {}
```

It's a slightly tidier way than querying the option directly.

Answer (score 5):

Checking for the option value `jetpack_active_modules`.

[image: database option value]

<sup>Searching for `photon` in wp_options is how I found the `option_name`.</sup>

---

The following prints the option as an admin notice:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse_75103_active_jetpack_modules' );

function wpse_75103_active_jetpack_modules() 
{
    if( !current_user_can( 'delete_users' ) )
        return;

    $jetp = get_option( 'jetpack_active_modules' );

    $photon_active = ( in_array( 'photon', $jetp ) ) ? 'is' : 'is not';
    echo '<h1>Photon ' . $photon_active . ' active</h1>';

    echo '<h2>All JetPack Options</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $jetp, true ) . '</pre>';
}
```

---

The following is the result with all modules activate.
**The key numbers are in the order by which the modules were activated and should not be used as reference**.
<sup>*( [in a local host installation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/42352/12615) )*</sup>

```
Array
(
    [0] => vaultpress
    [1] => photon
    [3] => notes
    [5] => publicize
    [7] => stats
    [9] => comments
    [11] => subscriptions
    [13] => post-by-email
    [15] => carousel
    [17] => sharedaddy
    [19] => after-the-deadline
    [21] => infinite-scroll
    [23] => enhanced-distribution
    [25] => json-api
    [27] => mobile-push
    [29] => widgets
    [31] => latex
    [33] => gravatar-hovercards
    [35] => contact-form
    [37] => minileven
    [39] => custom-css
    [41] => shortcodes
    [43] => shortlinks
)
```

Comment: Photon displays as number 19 for me... `[19] => photon`. Would it be better (in your opinion) to check the array for the presence of Photon as a value?

Comment: You can use PHP function [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check for Photon activation. I've updated the Answer to include an example of how to check this *(which was your Question in the first place)* :)