# Active Plugins for current blog in WP Multisite Network?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, multisite

Simple question but I can't find an answer - how do I find whether the current blog in a multisite network has a given plugin activated (speaking about plugins that are available to all sites on the network but are NOT network activated)?

Comment: Have you tried going to the plugins page while on the individual site and looking at which ones are active?

Comment: I'm trying to load PHP conditionally based on whether a plugin is active within a theme so that wouldn't do me much good in context - thankfully I just found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `get_option('active_plugins)` does the trick. Also, this question has already been answered here, sorry for the duplicate:

[How to Check If A Plugin Is Enabled Through API?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14410/how-to-check-if-a-plugin-is-enabled-through-api)